# Get the unchecked nodes of Kendo tree view

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a requirement where I need to delete the parent node if none of the children nodes are checked.
I just needed to know how can I check for the unchecked state of a node in kendo tree view.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Are you using knockout.js?

Comment: No I am not using knockout.